# How to assign child(s) to Product Backlog Item in TFS Template

Tags: templates, tfs

We have same tasks in some product backlog items(pbi) and each time we have to create pbi and tasks and same things, only there is a little bit differences. So we want to create a template pbi and tasks and we did but we could not assign tasks to pbi. as we checked the fields, there is no 'parent Id' or something like that.

how to do that? I can accept also that we can write a powershell script.

Version is Version 16.131.27701.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot add the relations into the TFS work item template, we can only set the available fields' value for a specific work item type in the work item template. Please see [Use templates to add and update work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/work-item-template?view=vsts&tabs=browser) for details.

So we cannot assign child(s) to a PBI in TFS work item template. However we can assign the child(s) by REST API ([Add a Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/previous-apis/wit/work-items?view=tfs-2018#add-a-link)) .

For example:

```
PATCH http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/111?api-version=4.0

Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
  {
    "op": "test",
    "path": "/rev",
    "value": 8
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
      "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward",
      "url": "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/{ProjectName or ID}/_apis/wit/workItems/129",
      "attributes": {
        "comment": "Add child link to PBI"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

You can use below PowerShell script to assign multiple child work items to a specific parent PBI:

```
Param(
   [string]$baseurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection",  
   [string]$projectName = "0511ScrumTFVC",
   [string]$PBI = "111",
   [string]$user = "Domain\user",
   [string]$token = "Password"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$uri = "$baseurl/_apis/wit/workitems/$($PBI)?api-version=4.0"

#For non-continuous child work item IDs
#$childs = (130,134,136)

#For Continuous child work item IDs
$childs = (130..134) #This will link child work item 130,131,132,134 to PBI 111

foreach ($child in $childs)
{

function CreateJsonBody
{
    $value = @"
[
  {
    "op": "test",
    "path": "/rev",
    "value": 8
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
      "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward",
      "url": "$baseurl/$projectName/_apis/wit/workItems/$child",
      "attributes": {
        "comment": "Add child work itme $child to PBI $PBI"
      }
    }
  }
]

"@

 return $value
}

$json = CreateJsonBody
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method PATCH -Body $json -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, probably I will use the API but can I implement this script into TFS or somehow it will be called externally? I did not see any information regarding it in your links

Comment: @ertan2002 You can run the script on any machine which can access the TFS server. Another way is creating a build definition and running the script with `PowerShell` task,

Comment: I thought so but this has to be executed only once? Because I thought that I should install a kind of plugin. If I execute the code only one time, will I be able to tie tasks to a parent? That was the my question. Thank you,

Comment: Yeah, you have to run the script every time when you create new PBI and tasks, as the work item IDs are different every time. You need to replace the corresponding IDs in the script to tie tasks to parent. As far as I know, no such plugins/extensions to achieve that for now (only run one time)...